# How to put multiple destination port ranges in ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have a long list of destination port ranges, `12000-13000, 2000-3000, 443`. How do I put all these port ranges in the ARM templates?

```
{
    "name": "test-nsg",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
    "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "properties": {
        "securityRules": [                {
                "name": "Allow ports",
                "properties": {
                    "priority": 1000,
                    "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                    "protocol": "TCP",
                    "destinationPortRanges": [
                        "443",
                        ""
                    ],
                    "access": "Allow",
                    "direction": "Inbound",
                    "sourcePortRange": "*",
                    "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
                }
            }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the list constant or do the ranges vary? Have you looked into passing a parameter and assigning the input parameter to the property?

Comment: The list is constant. Yes, I agree with you in the case of dynamic ranges, parameter works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple destination port ranges in your arm template as shown in below

```
"destinationPortRanges":  ["1200-1300","2000-3000","443","22"]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can pass those multiple destinations port ranges values by creating a parameter for ports of type array & calling those parameters in the resources block  as shown in below

```
"parameters":{
   "port":{
      "type":"array",
      "defaultValue":[
         "1200-1300",
         "15000-16000",
         "443"
      ]
   }
}
```

In resources block :

```
  "destinationPortRanges":  "[parameters('port')]"
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfect, thanks